# Modulus not returning remainder of a number

Tags: c++

I am trying to simulate a brute force attack using an additive cipher and i need to use modulus on some numbers but when i try to use the modulus operator "%" it never seems work here is my code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() 
{
    char cipherText [15] = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX";
    char guess [] = " ";
    int numArray [15];
    int modArray [15];
    int finalArray[15];
    char alpha [26] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
                'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    //Get Number for each letter
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(cipherText); x++)
    {    
        char c = cipherText[x];
        int num = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(alpha);i++)
        {
            if(c == alpha[i])
            {
                num = num + 0;
                break;
            } 
            else
            {
                num = num + 1;
            }    
        }
        numArray[x] = num;
        //cout<<" "<<numArray[x];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {  

        cout<<endl;

        for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        {
            int j;
            if(i == 0)
            {
                j = numArray[x];
            }
            else
            {    
                j = numArray[x]-i;
            } 
            modArray[x] = j;
            //cout<<modArray[x]<<" ";
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        {    

            int y = (modArray[x])%26;
            cout<<modArray[x]<<" ";
        }




        cout<<endl;
    }    
}
```

the output stays as the array of numbers minus i. i dont know why this isnt working any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Did you intend `cout<<y<<" ";`?

Comment: That is what is intended. I made an error in that code but above that line it should read modArray[x] = y;

Comment: A hint: Concerning `//Get Number for each letter`: To convert a capital character to a value in range [0, 26), you may use e.g. `int num = chr - 'A';`. (This will work with ASCII, and I doubt you're platform is using something else like EBCDIC.)

Comment: Another hint: You have correctly allocated 15 characters to store `"UOISCXEWLOBDOX"` (incl. the silent `'\0'` terminator) in `cipherText`. `sizeof(cipherText)` will hence return 15, and this involves the `'\0'` terminator in the loops. (It has index 14 - the highest valid index in `char cipherText[15]`.) I hardly believe this is intended. May be, it's better to introduce a length variable which is one less than size.

Comment: Another hint: There are a lot of [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/7478597) in your code. I would initially introduce variables for these values. It makes the code better maintainable. (It prevents unintended side effects when a certain detail is changed somewhere.) E.g. `char cipherText [] = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX";` <- let the compiler count the number of elements; `const size_t size = sizeof cipherText;` <- this is a constant which can be used for dimension of related arrays. `const size_t len = size - 1;` <- for loops consider "pay load" only.

Comment: Concerning your title: _Modulus not returning remainder of a number_ I simply don't believe this. I really (really, really) cannot imagine that something simple like the modulo operator is broken on your system. What I could imagine is that it does not yield the expected values. (Because your expectation is wrong?) I believe you urgently should go step by step through your code with a debugger to see what _really_ happens. (I must admit that even after 20 ... 30 years developing, I'm still sometimes surprised how values in debugger differ from my expectation and why.) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with the intermediate arrays is vastly overcomplicated, and you're unnecessarily using low-level primitives. The code can be made quite simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::string cipherText = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX";
    constexpr int alphabetSize = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; i++) {  
        std::string encryptedText(cipherText.size(), ' ');
        std::transform(cipherText.begin(), cipherText.end(), encryptedText.begin(),
            [=](char c){
                return ((c + i - 'A') % alphabetSize) + 'A';
            }
        );
        std::cout << encryptedText << std::endl;
    }
}
```

There is the assumption made about the linearity of the `'A' - 'Z'` range, but you'd be hard-pressed to find a machine that doesn't do that.

This assumption allows for the logic of the code to essentially condense to this one line:

```
return ((c + i - 'A') % alphabetSize) + 'A';
```

It might seem a bit weird at first, but it gets easier once you realize that the `-'A'` and `+'A'` parts are there just to map the character to the 0-26 range, so that the modulo operation could be utilized. You could obviously split this up into multiple transformations, doing it in more steps (e.g. subtract `'A'`, add `i`, do the modulo, add `'A'`).

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator is working fine.

You are getting negative values because of

`j = numArray[x]-i`.

I just printed your **numArray** and it comes out to be `20 14 8 18 2 23 4 22 11 14 1 3 14 23 26` for one instance. Now you are subtracting `i` from each element in your numArray because of which your resulting array have negative values.